# Installing Firefox addon forever as load-temporary add-on

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

### Briefly

I don't know, how I can download GhostText for Firefox 49.0.2, so I did not have to reinstall GhostText at each session in Firefox.

---

---

### Detail

I want to use [**GhostText**](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText). GhostText collaborator [**tell me**](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText/issues/88#issuecomment-257918334), what [**addon on Mozilla site**](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/ghosttext-for-firefox/) not worked and I need install GhostText [**manually**](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText/tree/master/browser#on-firefox). I need visit `about:debugging#addons` in Firefox →
click on `Load Temporary Add-on` and select the file `browser/manifest.json` inside my cloned project.

Now GhostText worked for me, but if I close Firefox, I need reinstall GhostText. I don't want reinstall GhostText each time, I want install addon one time and use it.

---

---

### Did not help

`about:addons` → click on `Settings` button → `Install Add-On From File`. It is solution for `.xpi` or `.jar` extensions, if I select `manifest.json`, I saw Firefox message:

> This add-on could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt.

[image: Firefox message]

I can not search other solutions in Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not compile xpi via [**jpm console utility**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm), but I solved my problem use [**XPI Compiler addon**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpicompiler/?src=dp-dl-othersby).

Install addon → paste or print `about:xpiler` in Firefox address bar → click the folder with magnifier icon → select `Your\GhostText\Folder\browser` folder, (for example, I install GhostText in `E` disk, my path is `E:\GhostText\browser`) → click to puzzle with arrow icon → build must compile successfully.

[image: XPI Compiler]

For those who know the Russian language, for more details [**see my answer on Stack Overflow**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/595371/199934).